# Sealant for two metal surfaces for oil filter housing

Tags: gasket, gasket-maker, lamborghini

I have an oil filter housing (located on the top of the block) that has a crossover tube that connects to it which runs from the back to the front of the V10 engine. The end of it I believe is connected to the dry sump oil pump. Oil pressure can reach 50-60psi and the temperature up to maybe 190 F.

The gasket that is between the oil filter housing and the block is a metal reinforced gasket coated with some rubber or something else that is deteriorating (19 years old). The cost of a new gasket is $1000 so I'm trying to avoid buying a new one.

Can I use some sort of gasket maker material or a sealant such as Optimum Black RTV sealant as a replacement?

Vehicle is a 2004 Lamborghini Gallardo.

Comment: Ok, exotic car and engine.  Are you sure you want to put some sort of makeshift gasket in this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: @jwh20 i'm ok with a makeshift gasket but want to go for the next optimal solution - if there is one

Comment: Remind me not to buy a Lamborghini unless I can also afford a $1000 oil filter gasket.

Answer (score 1):

This is the part you're talking about?

[image]

If so, then no. You need to use a direct replacement part. However, it doesn't mean you *have to use one from Lamborghini*. I did a cursory search on the internet for
[Lamborghini 07L103161D](https://www.google.com/search?q=lamborghini+07L103161D&oq=lamborghini+07L103161D) and found them at about 10% of what you are talking about. Do your research and I'm sure you can find something your pocket book can stomach.

Comment: @paulster2 i had come across that website which shows it at ~10% the cost as well but it's not a legit business. Why does this gasket need to be a direct replacement?

Comment: @Jay - I'm not sure how you discerned the website is not a legit business, but I'll leave that up to your judgement since it's your money/vehicle on the line. -  It needs to be a direct replacement for two reasons. 1) It does more than seal. If you look at it, the gasket also routes the oil. You can't get that with gasket maker alone. 2) There is a thickness to it. If you don't use something comparable, the filter housing will not sit right on the engine.

Comment: Thank you for your input - the factory seals will be used to ensure proper sealing, oil routing, and thickness tolerances.

Answer (score 1):

Given the cost of the engine, and the rarity of the vehicle, you're better off to avoid bodge repairs.

Spend the money to maintain the car, and it will appreciate in value over time.  It is not a disposable vehicle, and the downside of that is cost.

If you can't afford to maintain it, either park it up in secure climate controlled storage, or sell it and get a more affordable car.

The cost of the engine lunching itself would be far more than the cost of the factory-correct part.